# ArangoDB document nested property naming convention and indexing limitations

Tags: indexing, properties, nested, arangodb

Problem:  indexing nested property in arangodb

Context: ArangoDB, community edition, running localy

Description:
I have a collection CONFIGURATIONS_NODES hosting documents with the following structure

{
"_sectionName": "MySection",
"_configurationName": "abc",
"nodeData": {
"_id": "61cc20793b83b2001c24a9ad",
"configuration_name": "xyz"
}

If I run a query
"for v in CONFIGURATIONS_NODES filter v.nodeData._id=="61cc20793b83b2001c24a9ad"  return v". It finds the document as expected but alas its a full scan.

If I try to create an index on the nested nodeData._id property the index creation fails. I was able to create an index on the nested property nodeData.configuration_name. so it seems the issue relates only to the nested _id

Comment: Do you _need_ to call it nodeData._id or can you get away with nodeData.id?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/indexing-index-basics.html) states:

> You cannot use the _id system attribute in user-defined indexes, but indexing _key, _rev, _from, and _to is possible.

The name `_id` conflicts with the internal `_id` attribute and is treated specially. Even though it is not mentioned in the documentation, this means that attributes named `_id` cannot be indexed, not even in nested subobjects.